# How do I calculate the theoretical max speed of a motor?

Tags: stepper, motor, speed, knowledgebase

I'd like to know how to estimate the maximum speed of a stepper motor before the torque drop-off. There are several existing calculators of varying degrees of complexity for that:

- RepRap [calculator](https://www.reprapfirmware.org/emf.html)
- Alex Kenis provides a [spreadsheet](https://alexkenis.wordpress.com/2018/03/06/supplemental-equations-and-links-for-stepper-motor-calculations/) (see also links therein)
- Many thanks to Ryan Carlyle for his answer to "[Real life stepper speed](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/a/625/)" here on 3D Printing.SE
- Zalophus Dokdo's [Stepper Motors Calculator](https://zalophusdokdo.github.io/StepperMotorsCalculator/en/index.html)
- CNC.xyz's [Stepper Motor Calculations](https://wiki.cnc.xyz/Stepper_Motor_Calculations)

However, some of them simply don't explain all the math behind the numbers, there are differences [see issue #38](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/a/625/) between real-life measurements and theoretical predictions, and all the notation is a bit inconsistent.

It is possible to do the calculations using full ODEs and all that sort of jazz, but it's too much for a single motor. I prefer to see it as a black box with some exposed parameters, nothing more.

What I've got so far boils down to EMF:

$A = 1.8^\circ$, angle per full step

$U = 24\ V$, voltage

$P = 2\ mm$, pitch

$N_t = 20$, teeth per gear

$N_{ms} = 16$, microsteps per full step

$v = 200\ mm/s$, desired speed

$T_h = 0.4, Nm$, holding torque

$I_r = 1.5\ A$, rated current

$R = 5.75\ Ohm$, phase resistance

$e = 75%$, stepper current

$L = 8.4\ mH$, motor inductance

$f = 200\ kHz$, max step rate, see Klipper [docs](https://www.klipper3d.org/Features.html)

Derived variables:

$N_s = 360^\circ / A = 200\ step/rev$, ***full*** steps per revolution

$d = P * N_t = 40\ mm/rev$, distance per revolution

$d_s = d / N_s = 0.2\ mm$, distance per ***full*** step

$d_{ms} = 1000 * d_s / N_{ms} = 12.5\ \mu m$, distance per *micro*step

$I_e = I_r * e / 100 = 1.125\ A$, effective max current

$RD = N_s * N_{ms} / d = 80\ step/mm$, rotational distance (is it supposed to be *micro*steps/mm?)

$v_{max} = f * 1000 / RD = 2500\ mm / s$, max theoretical speed at this rate

$RPM_m = 60 * (v / d) = 300\ rev/min$, revolutions per minute at speed $v$; [Alex](https://alexkenis.wordpress.com/2018/03/06/supplemental-equations-and-links-for-stepper-motor-calculations/) also multiplies by $N_s$ and divides by a magic number 200, both really make no sense to me

$RPS_m = RPM_m / 60 = 5\ rev/sec$, revolutions per second

$\xi_r = \sqrt 2 * \pi * T_h * (RPS_m/I_r) \approx 5.9\ V$, [rotation EMF](https://alexkenis.wordpress.com/2018/03/06/supplemental-equations-and-links-for-stepper-motor-calculations/). This is the point where questions start to arise though. I found another source [("Back emf due to rotation of stepper moto")](https://www.oyostepper.com/article-1102-Back-emf-due-to-rotation-of-stepper-motor.html) where the rated current is used as well. To me, it looks like should be $I_e$ even for peak EMF values since the current is limited by the corresponding driver. There is also an argument [in issue #38](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/a/625/) regarding the coefficients that should be used in practice

$\xi_i = RPS_m * \pi *I_e * (L/1000) * (N_s/2) \approx 14.8\ V$, Alex uses magic numbers again, I also failed to find the actual source for this formula

Now, since I'm not sure these values/formulas are valid I can't move to the next part that's calculations of the maximum achievable speed. Even more so, there are [two](https://alexkenis.wordpress.com/2018/03/06/supplemental-equations-and-links-for-stepper-motor-calculations/) [formulas](https://www.reprapfirmware.org/emf.html) that introduce even more confusion.

I'd be happy to see some solid advice or potential sources to read.